# how to sync API call on different tabs of a browser

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, cross-browser

> is there any way to call an api on multiple tabs in a browser? for
> example in tab A i called the apple API with data A, and in tab B i
> call that same apple API but with data B. so now the tab A apple API
> should also have data B. is there a way to achieve this using react
> and node?

Answer (score 1):

how about using Broadcast Channel API? which needs web webWorker

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API

I am not sure it is you are looking for

Comment: let me look into this thanks :D